# Two datasets on a log scale y-axis and another on secondary axis with title

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot columns A and B on the left Y axis on a *log10scale*, and column C on the right axis on a normal scale. X axis would be the first column of my data, `Time`.

My data is:

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 4
     Time       A     B     C
    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
        1   33046   196  0.81
        2  970250   578  0.94
        3 1870125   323  2.31
        4  259625   509 12.20
        5 3838750   215 11.50
        6  962333  5437  4.70
        7 2272917 41028 10.10
```

I have tried:

```r
plot(data$Time, data$A, type = "l",  xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL,
     log = "y", main = "Title", xlab = "Time", ylab = "copies", col= "blue")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(data$Time, data$B, type = "l",  xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL,
     log = "y", main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "", col= "green", add=TRUE)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(data$C, type = "l", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",
     ylab = "", xlab = "", col = "red", lty = 2, )
axis(side = 4)
mtext("secondary axis", side = 4, line = 3)
legend("topleft", c("A", "B", "C"),
       col = c("blue", "green", "red"), lty = c(1, 2))
```

- How can I plot both A and B on a log scale (10^2-10^6) on y1 without overlapping?
- How can I add the y2 axis title?

This is the graph I got using the code above:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the same limits for both plots to have the same axis. That's why I have `ylim = c(100,10000000)` in both plots.

You need to define the proper margin and plot boundaries to be able to show everything. That's what `par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.1)` does.

In the `legend` you need to specify the line type for all your traces; so, `lty = c(1, 2)` is not right since makes `B` trace dashed in the legend while `C` is dashed. I used `lty = c(1, 1, 2)` for that.

Also, I used `col="red"` in `mtext` to make it clear that secondary axis is for `C`, which is also in `red`.

```r
data <- structure(list(Time = 1:7, 
                          A = c(33046, 970250, 1870125, 259625, 3838750, 962333, 2272917), 
                          B = c(196, 578, 323, 509, 215, 5437, 41028), 
                          C = c(0.81, 0.94, 2.31, 12.2, 11.5, 4.7, 10.1)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -7L), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

opar <- par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.1)

plot(data$Time, data$A, type = "l",  xlim = NULL, ylim = c(100,10000000),
     log = "y", main = "Title", xlab = "Time", ylab = "copies", col= "blue")

par(new = TRUE)
plot(data$Time, data$B, type = "l",  xlim = NULL, ylim = c(100,10000000),
     log = "y", main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "", col= "green")

par(new = TRUE)
plot(data$C, type = "l", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",
     ylab = "", xlab = "", col = "red", lty = 2, )
axis(side = 4)

mtext("secondary axis", side = 4, line = 3, col="red")
legend("topleft", c("A", "B", "C"),
       col = c("blue", "green", "red"), lty = c(1, 1, 2)) 
par(opar)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>